# Bigquery exporting tables in GCS of file size 8GB even using single wildcard URI to export the table in less than 1 gb chunksof file

Tags: google-bigquery, export, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I tried manually and  with command line to export big query table having 140GB of data into files of size less than 1GB in GCS bucket. It created 168 files overall after export. All files from 1 to 167 are of less than 1GB but the last file is around 8GB for both case while exporting using command line or using big query interface.

Here is screenshot of GCS bucket.[image]

I followed [Export bigquery table to GCS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_data_stored_in) to export table into multiple file using single wildcard uri to split the exported table into chunks.

I want all exported files to be around 1 GB only. Can anybody help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read the documentation wrong.

There is no 1GB per file export configuration in BigQuery.

The 1GB what you [have read](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_data_stored_in) is referring to the data size that you are trying to export.

> If you are exporting more than 1 GB of data, you must export your data
>   to multiple files. When you export your data to multiple files, the
>   size of the files **will vary**.

So this tells that if your table is bigger than 1GB you must export to multiple files. But it DOESN'T tell you that the files will be smaller than 1GB, it tells the file size varies.

Comment: However, I agree with @ascii_walker, the behavior is strange. I recommend you to open a Support case to be sure that is the intended behavior.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I already did this like a couple of years ago, they corrected the documentation page. It clearly states now the "file size varys". That's the most they could do.